# Confidence Intervals of a Given Width

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, standardization, quantiles, coverage-probability

I'm working through some questions on confidence intervals. My answer doesn't match the book, but the book's answer was a number I had a few steps before the end.

> I have ten numbers which are a random sample from a normal
>   distribution with standard deviation $\sigma = 135$. The sample mean
>   is $1008$.
>
> If a $C\%$ confidence interval has width $100$, what is $C$?

**What I've done:**

The sample mean is $1008$, so a confidence interval of width $100$ would be $[958,1058].$ I first tried to convert these limits into $z$-scores.

The CLT tells us that the sample means will be distributed normally with standard deviation
$$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{135}{\sqrt{10}}$$

I used the general formula $X= \mu + \sigma Z$ on the upper-limit $\bar{X} = 1058$ to give 
$$Z=\frac{50\sqrt{10}}{135} \approx 1.1712$$

To find $C$, I need to find $P(-1.1712 \le Z \le 1.1712)$.

Using the tables I get $P(Z \le 1.1712) = 0.8792$, which gives
$$P(-1.1712 \le Z \le 1.1712) = 0.7585$$

**I would conclude that a $76\%$ confidence interval would have width of $100$. However, the textbook says it's an $88\%$ confidence interval.**

As you can see, I got $P(Z \le 1.1712) \approx 0.88$.

It feels like the solutions have missed out the last step.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. You do not even need the CLT since the sample is normal.

Comment: It's a school textbook. Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it!